# connecting three computers to one hive instance

Tags: hive

Good day,i have a need to use hive just the way we could use mysql. I want to find a way in which I can host it online so that people in different places can communicate to one hive service. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the functionality that Hive Server 2 provides

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+Up+HiveServer2

It exposes Hive as a thrift web service, and there are JDBC and ODBC drivers available.

You can also put Apache Knox in front of it, in order to have more options for authentication and authorization https://knox.apache.org/

If you are using a common distribution such as Hortonworks or Cloudera, Hive Server 2 will probably be installed automatically when you install Hive.

Comment: Thanks mattinbits. I actually used hiveserver instead of hiveserver2 because it seems my hadoop is using port 10000 and hiveserver2 can't connect to it .so Using hive --service hiveserver -p9000& worked but does not work for hiveserver2. Is there any other way I can bind hiveserver2 to a port of my choice. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what is running on port 10000? It may mean that HiveServer2 is already running on your system.

Comment: I think its hadoop. I checked before I started the hiveserver